# Using DateTime why do I sometimes have to put System.DateTime in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I am really new to Visual Studio, so this may be a really obvious question, apologies in advance!

I'm trying to set up a new DateTime and I've noticed that depending on the project that I'm in I have to reference them differently to get them to work.

In the first project I can reference it like this without an error:

```
DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
```

However in my second project if I put exactly the same piece of code I get the error message:

```
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ProgPractice.DateTime.Now'
```

In order to get around the error I have to put system in front of the DateTime like this:

```
System.DateTime theDate = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Could someone explain why, or point me to a resource so that I understand the difference? I've Googled it, but I don't think I'm using the right terminology.

Thanks!

---EDIT---

I have using System; at the top of my file.

I'd named my second project DateTime.aspx and I think that was causing the conflict. Thanks for all your help, wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: Do you have `using System;` directive at the top ?

Comment: Does the top of your file have using System

Comment: You have a naming conflict. Don't name your things the same thing as built in names. Check your `ProgPractice` namespace or class to see if it has a field or property called `DateTime`, which is conflicting with the built in `System.DateTime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second project also contains a class DateTime, which is confusing the compiler, because it can't know which one to use without adding the namespace.

You can solve this the way you found out, or change the other uses of DateTime to ProgPractice.DateTime and removing the using ProgPractice reference from the page. The opposite works as well: adding 'using System;' if it's not already present.

Comment: I'd named my project DateTime which I think was causing the issue - thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score -2):

you need to using System;  above your namespace

Comment: Adding the using you've suggested would never get rid of "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ProgPractice.DateTime.Now'"